# Putting a number into a range with php

Tags: php

I am working on a job board at the minute that allows a user to post a too and from salary that comes in a POST like this,

`$_POST['sal_from']` & `$_POST['sal_to']` this POST comes a from a third party so sadly I am not sure of what the validation is however lets assume that number must always be thousands.

A user would submit something like from - 10000 to - 20000, what I want to is somehow turn that number into a 2 figure representation and then show a range, so the above would show as >10k-20k.

Is this possible, I can figure out how, ideally i need to look out for the following ranges,

- 10k-20k
- 20k-25k
- 25k-30k
- 30k-35k
- 40k+

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Using [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function, you can specify negative precision values also. So, you can specify **-1** as precision value, to round to the nearest Tens.

You can use a function like below, to convert a number to abbreviated string.

```
function convertFormat($value) {

    if ($value > 1000000000000) {
        $value = round($value / 1000000000000, -1) . 'T';
    } elseif ($value > 1000000000) {
        $value = round($value / 1000000000, -1) . 'B';
    } elseif ($value > 1000000) {
        $value = round($value / 1000000, -1) . 'M';
    } elseif ($value > 1000) {
        $value = round($value / 1000, -1) . 'K';
    } else {
        $value = round($value);
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Now, you can run this function on `$_POST['sal_from']` and `$_POST['sal_to']` separately, to get the range.

Comment: I would recommend using `>=` So that it matches on `1000000000000` as `1T` instead of `1,000B`